# copy text from excel file and paste in browser

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, python-3.x

I have this working using html table and javascript. i thought it was a one off but now other departments within the company want to use it.  i need to make something the user can alter as they please, the way it is now the comments are hard coded (i know a really bad idea).  I was thinking about excel but not everyone has it.  So Im down to the idea of a text file.

Sample of the html as it is no looks like this:

The label describing the comment and then the text of the comment next to it on one row of the table.

Comment 1                   This is the text to copy

Ive tried to find a similar solution but cant find what Im looking for.  If anyone has a idea please post.  Thanks.

Comment: Based on your description, I'm not quite sure what it is that you are trying to do. Where does the copy and paste come in? Maybe you could share your HTML table and working javascript?

Comment: https://github.com/austenr0430/NewCG

Comment: What I want to do is find a way that each user can create their own comments.  None can code and would be lost.  I was thinking about some sort of text file that the user can change and the number of comments could change dynamically.  However, after thinking about that they might mess that up too.  No one has Excel except a few which would be a workable solution but everyone has Google sheets.  I thought about that but Im not that good with that.

Comment: I would be open to another approach like python, etc.

Comment: How are you deploying this? If you use Python you'll need a "back end". If you stick with JS then it can all be done in the browser.